# spring security unable to locate espaceHandler for XML schema namespace

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-security, gradle

I wanted to add `spring security` to my project. It uses `gradle` for resolving dependencies and `vaadin` for UI and `tomcat` as servlet container.

So I created `pmc-security-context.xml`, which looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user" password="pass" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

I added it to my `contextConfiguration` in `web.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/pmc-web-context.xml
            classpath:/pmc-web-security-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>another-pmc-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ru.xpoft.vaadin.SpringVaadinServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>beanName</param-name>
            <param-value>pmcVaadin</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfiguration</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>another-pmc-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I added dependency to `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.5.RELEASE'
```

But when I try to start tomcat using `gradle tomcatRun` I've got this error

```
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locat
espaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security]
Offending resource: class path resource [pmc-web-security-context.xml]

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionP
e.java:1424)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionP
e.java:1417)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(Defaul
ionDocumentReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(D
finitionDocumentReader.java:144)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(Def
nitionDocumentReader.java:100)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefiniti
a:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinition
392)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionRe
6)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionRe
4)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBe
Reader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBe
Reader.java:216)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBe
Reader.java:187)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicatio
a:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicatio
a:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(Abstract
pplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplica
java:537)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.jav
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:1
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.Contex
ner
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locat
espaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security]
Offending resource: class path resource [pmc-web-security-context.xml]

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionP
e.java:1424)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionP
e.java:1417)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(Defaul
ionDocumentReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(D
finitionDocumentReader.java:144)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(Def
nitionDocumentReader.java:100)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefiniti
a:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinition
392)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionRe
6)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionRe
4)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBe
Reader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBe
Reader.java:216)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBe
Reader.java:187)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicatio
a:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicatio
a:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(Abstract
pplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplica
java:537)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.jav
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:1
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Error listenerStart
Context [/pmc-web] startup failed due to previous errors
Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicastin
 the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Dec 20 06:01:22 BRT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(Abstrac
Context.java:344)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContex
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.jav
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5035)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5687)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle m
he context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Dec 20 06:01:22 BRT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicat
ava:357)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.jav
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5035)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5687)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextL
r
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing
he ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefr
cationContext.java:170)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContex
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.jav
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5035)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5687)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Failed to check for ThreadLocal references for web application [/pmc-web]
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadedByThisOrChild(WebappClassLoader.java:2636)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks(WebappClassLoader.java:2552)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.checkThreadLocalsForLeaks(WebappClassLoader.java:2507)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferences(WebappClassLoader.java:2013)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.stop(WebappClassLoader.java:1908)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.stopInternal(WebappLoader.java:661)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5730)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Why? What's configured wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the spring configuration dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version> 
    </dependency>
```

Replace the version with the one you currently use.